# Re-use downloaded image in Custom List Adapter with Picasso

Tags: android

I am trying to re-use images that are already downloaded when I scroll up the list, but Picasso fetches all the images again from the network. This is evident from the red tag in the image.

[image: android picasso]

I used this [code](https://github.com/square/picasso/blob/master/picasso-sample/src/main/java/com/example/picasso/SampleListDetailAdapter.java) as reference to use a ViewHolder in my custom list adapter:

```
   @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder holder;
        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_widget_redeem, parent, false);
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.image = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.redeem_icon);
            convertView.setTag(R.string.image_holder, holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag(R.string.image_holder);
        }

        TextView titleView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.redeem_title);

        RedeemStrategy currentStrategy = getItem(position);
        titleView.setText(currentStrategy.getName());
        Picasso picasso = new Picasso.Builder(context).listener(new Picasso.Listener() {
            @Override
            public void onImageLoadFailed(Picasso picasso, Uri uri, Exception exception) {
                exception.printStackTrace();
            }
        }).indicatorsEnabled(true).build();
        picasso.load(AndroidApplication.context.getString(R.string.base_url) + currentStrategy.getLogo())
                .tag(context)
                .into(holder.image);

        convertView.setTag(currentStrategy.getId());

        return convertView;
    }

    @Override public RedeemStrategy getItem(int position) {
        return redeemStrategies.get(position);
    }

    static class ViewHolder {
        ImageView image;
    }
```

How can I get Picasso to re-use the images that are already downloaded?

Comment: I'm not sure if that's the reason but you should try to reuse the same Picasso instance rather than creating a new one every time.

Comment: wow, that was the issue. can you write that as an answer? I can mark as right

Comment: done, glad I could help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should reuse the same Picasso instance rather than creating a new one every time.